# Python modify __getattribute__

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, getattribute

I want to modify the behaviour of _*getattribute*_ in "Parent class" (the reason is that a number of attributes are inside an XML element and for other reasons I don't want to dump all the information from the XML element to the class as attributes).
The approach I have tried is to define an attribute in the class that collects the name of the attributes that must be searched inside the XML element (only in these ones the behaviour of _*getattribute*_ is altered).

**Important!** I'm going to write a simple example because the problem is only in _*getattribute*_ method and not in the XML management section.

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):

        self.parentAttr = "some string"

    @property
    def specialAttrs(self):
        return {"parentAttr"}

    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):

        if attr in self.specialAttrs:
            return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]

        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)

foo = Parent()
print(foo.parentAttr)
```

This error is raised

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 20
     17             return super().__getattribute__(attr)
     19 foo = Parent()
---> 20 print(foo.parentAttr)

Cell In[12], line 13, in Parent.__getattribute__(self, attr)
     11 def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):
---> 13     if attr in self.specialAttrs:
     14         return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]
     16     else:

Cell In[12], line 13, in Parent.__getattribute__(self, attr)
     11 def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):
---> 13     if attr in self.specialAttrs:
     14         return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]
     16     else:

    [... skipping similar frames: Parent.__getattribute__ at line 13 (2970 times)]

Cell In[12], line 13, in Parent.__getattribute__(self, attr)
     11 def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):
---> 13     if attr in self.specialAttrs:
     14         return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]
     16     else:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Obviously, the class tries to look for specialAttrs attribute. This originate a recursive search for specialAttrs.

A solution could be change self.specialAttrs by {"parentAttr"}

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):

        self.parentAttr = "some string"

    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):

        if attr in {"parentAttr"}:
            return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]

        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)

foo = Parent()
print(foo.parentAttr)
```

Prints:

```
SPECIAL! some string
```

But I need the ability to modify specialAttrs because other classes inherit specialAttrs and extend it.

```
class Son(Parent):

    def __init__(self):

        self.sonAttr = "other string"

        super().__init__()

    @property
    def specialAttrs(self):
        return super().specialAttrs.union({"sonAttr"})
```

I am a little bit stacked here. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

### EDIT 1 (Pranav Hosangadi suggestion)

This is the solution I proposed earlier, a little bit extended.

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):

        self.parentAttr = "some string"

    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):

        if attr in {"parentAttr"}:
            return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]

        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)


class Son(Parent):

    def __init__(self):

        self.sonAttr = "other string"

        super().__init__()


    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):

        if attr in {"sonAttr"}:
            return "SPECIAL! " + self.__dict__[attr]

        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)


foo = Son()
print(foo.parentAttr)
```

Prints:

```
SPECIAL! some string
```

It works.. BUT! I have to redefine the _*getattribute*_ method in each class that inherits from Parent. I would like to avoid this approach.

Comment: No. There is a rude solution that is writing all the special attributes in the classes. This way requieres to define __getattribute__ in all the classes. This way is a solution but I would like to know if there is a way to include a pure attibute in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you don't want any calls to `Parent.__getattribute__` *inside* the `Parent.__getattribute__` definition. As you have found out, doing `attr in self.specialAttrs` involves exactly this call: `self.specialAttrs` calls `self.__getattribute__('specialAttrs')`

To fix this, change that call to a `super().__getattribute__('specialAttrs')` like so:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parentAttr = "some string"
        self.regAttr = 3.14

    @property
    def specialAttrs(self):
        return {"parentAttr"}

    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str):
        if attr in super().__getattribute__('specialAttrs'):
            return "SPECIAL! " + super().__getattribute__(attr)
        else:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
```

Now, it works as expected:

```
foo = Parent()
print(foo.regAttr) # 3.14 
print(foo.parentAttr) # SPECIAL! some string
```

And you can extend `Parent` without having to redefine `__getattribute__`:

```
class Son(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sonAttr = "other string"
        self.regAttr = 6.28


    @property
    def specialAttrs(self):
        return super().specialAttrs.union({"sonAttr"})
    
bar = Son()
print(bar.regAttr) # 6.28
print(bar.parentAttr) # SPECIAL! some string
print(bar.sonAttr) # SPECIAL! other string
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

I was so focused on doing something very complex and I didn't see the simplest and most effective solution.

I have marked the question as solved!